# Subscription on numbers does not raise syntax error?

Tags: c

Why is the following program print -7 instead of throwing syntax error?
**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc , char **argv)
{
    int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int *b = arr + 6;
    printf("%d\n", -1[b]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What will really bake your noodle is `printf("%d\n", (-1)[b]);`

Comment: Subscription operates on *both* operands, not just one. It's also useful for code golfing... `digit["0123456789"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the index operator `a[b]` is just syntactic sugar, that literally translates into `*(a+b)` thus invoking pointer arithmetic which is commutative on its arguments. Hence it's perfectly allowed to swap the "inside" and the "outside" of `…[…]`.

Comment: @Cosinus `(void*)a + ...`  makes no sense. And in C it's true that `pointer_value + integer_value` gives the same as `integer_value + pointer_value`

Comment: @Cosinus: But this (what you've been suggesting) is *not* what the `index` does! The C specification (6.5.2.1  Array subscripting) literally states *"The definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`." (sic)* – Please read the spec (and then maybe delete your misleading comment).